# Do I need to run PSP System activation in order to use DLC

Tags: psn, psp

I have Disgaea 2: Dark Hero Days in which I can get DLC from the Australian PSN Store.

I plan to buy Black Rock Shooter from the UK PSN Store due to the fact that the licences agreement NISA made prevents them from selling it in a number of countries in which Australia is one of them.

Now I read that in order to play content from different PSN Stores the system has to be activated on that store which can be done by connecting the PSP to the PS3 and using the system action function (which I have to use due to the fact that the PSP is not compatible with my wireless encryption) however from what I read a PSP can't be activated for 2 accounts simultaneously.

I'm wondering if I can download DLC from the AU PSN Store then switch the activation to the UK PSN Store, download Black Rock Shooter and remain activated on the UK Store and still use the DLC I brought from the AUS PSN Store or if it would be better to get a separate PSP?

NOTE: I could just use the UK PSN Store to get the DLC but I have to wait almost 2 weeks to get UK PSN Cards while locally I can get them in 24 hours or less, even less if it's a weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to the question in your subject, Yes.

Activating a PSP for one region wipes the old account (and all downloaded content) off of the system when you assign it to the new region. In my experience DLC is generally regionally encoded as well.

What you read was correct. A PSP can only be active for one region, one account. Period.

To that end, you also can not store activated content on a memory card, switch cards, change regions and then switch the old memory card back. It will not accept the card activated against another account (even if it's the same region).

Your only legitimate option is to own two PSPs with each one activated for a different region or flip activations back and forth (but we warned, you only get a couple of activations per device, per year).